# nested list in c# (parent and child list)

Tags: c#, list, nested

I have a list which I want to convert into tree structure. How can I convert this into tree structure?

**QuestionDetails.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class QuestionDetails
{
    public int QID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int AnswerType { get; set; }
    //public string Question { get; set; }
    public IList<QuestionDetails> ChildLayers { get; private set; }  
    public QuestionDetails()
    {
        ChildLayers = new List<QuestionDetails>();
    }

}


public IList<QuestionDetails> daya()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); //
    cmd.CommandText = "selectdata";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    // da.Fill(ds.Tables["AnswerMaster"]);
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT = ds.Tables["Table"];
    DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
    DT1 = ds.Tables["Table1"];

    IList<QuestionDetails> data = ConvertDataTable<QuestionDetails>(DT);


    IList<QuestionDetails> hierarcy = new List<QuestionDetails>();
    //IList<ChildLayers> hierarcy1 = new List<ChildLayers>();

    foreach (var layer in data)
    {

        var sublayers = data.Where(i => i.QID == layer.QuestionID && i.QID != 0);

         if (sublayers.Any())
         {
             hierarcy.Add(layer);
         }

         foreach (var sublayer in sublayers)
         {
             layer.ChildLayers.Add(sublayer);    
         }
    }

    return hierarcy; 
}
```

And I want output in this format:

```
{
    question id=1
    Question ="asasaS"
    {
        ANSWER="SDASA";
        ANSWER="SADSAD";
        ANSWER="SADSA";
        ANSWER="SADSAD";
    }

    question id=2
    Question ="XCVXVXCVXC"
    {
        ANSWER="SDASA";
        ANSWER="SADSAD";
        ANSWER="SADSA";
        ANSWER="SADSAD";
    }
}
```

i want list data as nested list .please help
i have created class for list.  I have a list which I want to convert into tree structure. How can I convert this into tree structure?

Comment: You have `System.Web.Script.Serialization` are you expecting a Json as output?

Comment: nested list type data.means 1 question have multiple option ,so option should come under question

Comment: do you want to return `return hierarcy;` as Json?

Comment: DATA SHOULD BE AS PARENT AND CHILD FORMAT AS I  EXPLAIN

Comment: Please don't shout. people are here to help.

Comment: no i am not shouting just my caps key was on.

Comment: Either you are expecting a Json and don't know what Json is. or you simply want to export it into this weird formated string. If its json well fine it's an unclear dupe we can show you how to json and ignore some object property. If it's a weird string I just don't see what stop you from crafting it your self! use string format and escape the `"`.

Comment: You decide 1/. weird string or 2/. Json? Don't get me wrong, I'm not agressive I'm just trying to understand. Cause you never adress the Question about Json.

Comment: yes it can be in json format

Answer (score 1):

First let's talk about your object:
QuestionDetails can contains a list of QuestionDetails that contains a list of etc etc..

QuestionDetails should contains a `Question` and his list of `Answer`. And an answer should not be a `Question`.

So let's define those class: *Ignore the `[ScriptIgnore]` for now!*

```
class Question
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int QID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; private set; }
    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public Question( int questionID, string questionText, IList<Answer> answers )
    {
        Answers = answers;
        QuestionID = questionID;
        QuestionText = questionText;
    }

    public string ToWeirdString()
    {
        string sout = $"\tquestion id={QuestionID}\n" +
                        $"\tQuestion =\"{QuestionText}\"\n";
        sout += "\t{\n";
        foreach (var i in Answers)
        {
            sout += $"\t\tANSWER=\"{i.AnswerText}\";\n";
        }
        sout += "\t}\n";
        return sout;
    }
}

class Answer
{
    public Answer(string answerText, int answerType)
    {
        AnswerText = answerText;
        AnswerType = answerType;
    }

    public string AnswerText { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int AnswerType { get; set; }
}
```

Initialisation of a sample of Question:

```
List<Question> sample = new List<Question> {
                            new Question(1, "text1", new List<Answer> {
                                                        new Answer("Answer 1",1),
                                                        new Answer("Answer 2",1),
                                                        new Answer("Answer 3",2),
                                                        new Answer("Answer 4",1)
                                                        }
                                        ),
                            new Question(2, "text2", new List<Answer> {
                                                        new Answer("Answer 5",1),
                                                        new Answer("Answer 6",3),
                                                        new Answer("Answer 7",1),
                                                        new Answer("Answer 8",4)
                                                        }
                                        )
                        };
```

Getting your weird string:

```
var weirdString = "{\n"+string.Concat( sample.Select(x => x.ToWeirdString()+"\n\n") )+"}\n";
```

How simple is the Json serialisation? This simple:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(sample);
```

Don't forget your `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` and click the light bubble if you are missing the dll.

One simple line and it's look like this :

```
[
   {
      "QuestionID":1,
      "QuestionText":"text1",
      "Answers":[
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 1"
         },
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 2"
         },
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 3"
         },
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 4"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "QuestionID":2,
      "QuestionText":"text2",
      "Answers":[
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 5"
         },
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 6"
         },
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 7"
         },
         {
            "AnswerText":"Answer 8"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Ps: `[ScriptIgnore]` tell the `JavaScriptSerializer` to ignore this property.